# Rate limit on number of videos you can view?

Tags: html, video-streaming, html5-video, instagram, vine

I'm building an app that will stream Instagram and Vine videos, one after another indefinitely. The way I'm accomplishing this is by listening for events on the video, and when the "ended" event fires, a new video starts playing.

This works fine for a couple of minutes, but then the videos start coming in as black. The strange thing is, the videos are still seeking and firing events fine.

I can't seem to find documentation on a limit of how many videos you can watch in a row, does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: Update: Instagram is sending a 13 byte response to some of the videos. It's unclear why this is occurring, and at what interval it happens.

Comment: Could you share a fiddle with the code you're using with some example videos (if possible). And a dump of those 13 bytes may be helpful, I assume it's when you get this response that you are unable to show the video? What browser is this and what format are the videos in?